# Ruby/Regex: Take consonants and move them to end of word(string) and add "ay" after them

Tags: ruby, regex

I must "piglatinize" a word, meaning, take the first consonants in a word and move them to the end, and add "ay" at the end of that. For example:

"character" to "aracterchay"    or    "bundy" to "undybay"

This is what I have so far:

```
def piglatinize(word)
  if !word.downcase.split("")[0].match(/[aeiou]/)
    first_consonants = word.match(/\b([^aeiou]{1,})/)
    the_rest = word.gsub(first_consonants, "")
    new_word = the_rest + first_consonants + "ay"
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not go ahead and do it?

Comment: Cause I have no idea how to do it. How can I do it unless someone shows me first? I read the entire regex doc and it didn't help one bit.

Comment: Are you required to use regexes for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
def piglatinize(word)
      if !word.downcase.split("")[0].match(/[aeiou]/)
        first_consonants = word.match(/\b([^aeiou]{1,})/)
        the_rest = word.gsub(/#{first_consonants}/, "")
        new_word = "#{the_rest}#{first_consonants}ay"
      end
    end
```